# Создание сайта новостей.

Tags: php, база-данных

Попробуем. Вопрос может быть и глупый, но все же. Короткие новости может и разумно хранить в БД. А что насчет новостей на всю страницу и с фото? Новостей таких может быть и 100500. Хранятся ли они в БД  или для каждой новости создается .html файл? Какой принцип создания таких сайтов. Гуглил - там только про короткие новостишки и постики в бложичках. Ничего серьезного((.

Comment: А как вы считаете, базы данных предназначены хранить данные только до 100 записей в таблице, и не больше? И притом только до 240(например) символов для строчных типов? Так вот, это не так.  
Просто если вы посмотрите на хостинги, в т.ч. бесплатные, то там идет ограничение на объем бд, куда миллионы новостей и фоток не поместятся, отсюда может сложиться впечатление, что больше 2 гигов баз не бывает. Так вот, это не так.  
Архитектура бд и хранящиеся в ней данные зависят от задачи, которая решается. Если есть необходимость, то и статьи с фотками прекрасно могут храниться в бд хоть в base64...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Я пользуюсь беспл. хостингом, где можно хранить по-моему даже до 1000 таблиц в одной БД. Т.е. дело не в емкости и объеме данных, а в том, как в реальности организованы сайты новостей и т.п. Сейчас я напишу скрипт для работы с файлами html, завтра окажется, что нужно использовать БД.

Comment: @Deus wordpress видели ? так и организованы сайты новостей. :)

Comment: @eicto, стараюсь не смотреть в сторону готовых машинок. Более тем, в wp не видно ГДЕ эти файлики-новостишки находятся.

Comment: @Deus, не видно только по той причине, что вы не смотрели. Это раз. Два - эти "готовые машинки" потому и готовые, что работают и популярны. А значит вам у них есть чему учиться.

Comment: @xEdelweiss, загружал я себе wp. Открыл и смотрю - движок с кучей прибамбасов -  учиться-учиться и еще раз учиться. Накачать кучу литературы, видеоуроков и т.д., постигать новое, лучшее, светлое. Как-нибудь. Завтра. А сегодня - просто небольшой вопрос - как хранить новости? Хотя я решил, что это будут файлы html

Comment: @Deus, решение ваше неверное, и хороший совет - забудьте слово ведеоуроки - трата времени. по wordpress лучшая книжка это его собственная документация.

Comment: ну и WordPress не идеальный движок. А еще на нем пытаются делать магазины, какие то каталоги и потом говорят о его нерационаьности. Используйте его по назначению для блога и все будет нормально.
А в БД можно хранить и 1 млн. записей  и при нормально с ними работать

Comment: @varz62, я об этом же.

Comment: @Deus, о чём? О том, что не надо на WP лепить что ни попадя - так это очевидно. Но как новостной движок его посмотреть стоит. Для новичка там много чего полезного найдётся. А новости нужно хранить в БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала я бы посоветовал определиться с тем, что такое "новость". То есть тупо представить ту сущность в виде структуры данных. Допустим, самый примитивный вариант - "текст, дата публикации". Одно это уже предполагает, что с одной сущностью связаны 2 поля данных. Добавляем фото. Получается, три.  Но это совсем примитив, данных может быть больше: разделы, теги, автор, дата модификации (а то и история редактирования), флаг "публиковать/не публиковать", источник(и), связанные статьи и ещё куча всего-всего. BTW, что значит "фото"? Фото в заголовке? Фотографии, внедрённые в тело? Галерея внизу новости? Так это ещё до фига всего.

Теперь определяемся с операциями, которые над этой сущностью проделывать. Тут уж на что фантазии хватит, но даже с самой примитивной сущностью их можно проделывать много. Включая не только админские действия, но и действия пользователя. Например, отфильтровать новости по интервалу дат. Или даже просто реализовать постраничный вывод.

А теперь представим, как всё это реализовать без БД, с помощью "хранения в .html"...

Comment: @klopp,Однозначно все эти "атрибуты" хранить в БД - дата, название, автор, и путь на странцицу html, - новость-то состоит из хреновой кучи форматированного контент - в тексте абзацы, заголовки, соответстующие внедренные в текст картинки, всевозможные ссыли и ПР. Ведь наверное так, как-то

Comment: Зачем? Я не понимаю, зачем хранить сам текст на диске, если всё хранится в БД. Не считая геморроя с хранением самих файлов, если их больше сотен, да и связывания файлов с данными, возникнет ещё куча проблем. BTW, у меня в базах миллионы текстов, связанных с несколькими десятками таблиц, разваленых по 4 серверам - ни разу не возникало мысли что-то "хранить в .html" :-)

Comment: @klopp, Спасибо, я получил исчерпывающий ответ. Одно, что неясно - какой тип указать для поля таблицы, в котором будет хранится все эта конструкция с текстом, картинками и хтмл-разметкой.

Comment: text, очевидно. Только картинкам-то там что делать? Текст статьи или новости - это голая разметка.

Comment: @klopp, http://mvs.gov.ua/ на главной странице посредине новости - клик! - ого, с фотками и остальной байдой. Вряд ли это все храниться в БД.

Comment: Не "вряд ли", а "точно" хранится в БД. Они же не полные идиоты.

Comment: @klopp, ок. Не они, я - полный. Спасибо за ответы, будем работать в указанном направлении.

Comment: [тут](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/) кстати хорошая статья как надо обходиться с blob и text в mysql.